# Where can I find the 404-Error-Page?

Tags: impresspages

Where can I find the 404-Error-Page to edit in Impresspages 4.0?
I can't find the page in the editor (backend). And i can't also a page in file-tree from the instalation.

Answer (score 0):

Add file Theme/ThemeName/error404.php to your theme.

http://www.impresspages.org/docs/layout